# 代用ボタンのクリックを、本物のボタンに適用したい

Tags: html, css

代用ボタンのクリックを、本物のボタンに適用したいのですが、
方法が分かりません。
因みに本物のボタンは非表示になっています。

```
 <button type="button">代用ボタン</button>
 <input type="file" id="本物のボタン" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScriptを使わないと難しいと思います。

```css
#honmono {display: none;}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('honmono').click();">代用ボタン</button>
<input type="file" id="honmono" name="fileselect[]" multiple="multiple" />
```

こんな感じでしょうか。

Comment: 解決することが出来ました。
ありがとうございます。